# Assigning a value to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, assign

If I have the following for example:

```
int *x;
x = func(a);
```

For the statement: `x = func(a);`, do we say that we are returning an address to `x`? Or, how exactly do we read it?

**EDIT**: *Is it eligible to say that we are returning a pointer to `x`? If so, can you explain how this is done exactly? I mean, how are we returning a pointer?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x is a pointer, specifically to an int.  So it should be obvious that there are two memory locations used.  One for the pointer and one for the memory it's pointing to (assuming the pointer is not null).

The pointer itself holds a memory address, specifically the location of the memory it's pointing to.  Something like 0xa456e4fa.

Yes, func() is returning a pointer.  The prototype of func would look like the following..

```
int * func(someObj a); //I don't know the datatype of your parameter,
                       //so I'm just making something up.
```

Notice the return type is a pointer to an int.  From this and what I said previously, it should be obvious what this will return.  Something of the form 0xyyyyyy, or a memory address/pointer.  That memory address goes into your x pointer.

Remember that the pointer itself is not holding the data that it's pointing to, it is only the address.  There's really no reason you CAN'T return a pointer.  However, you do need to be careful in WHAT you return.  You do not want to return the address of a local variable because that variable will go out of scope once the function has completed its execution.  You'll then be returning the address of something invalid.  Returning the VALUE of a local pointer however, is fine because the value you returned (the address) will be preserved as will the memory it's pointing to.

I also just realized I wrote you a book.  Damn, I sure do ramble when I'm tired.

Answer (score 7):

`x` is a pointer to an `int`, so in other words it is the address of a memory location where an `int` is stored. So `x = func(a)` means that `func` returns the address of an `int` and stores it in the variable `x`.

Take care not to return the address of a local variable whose contents would be undefined after `func` returns.

Answer (score 4):

RE: Your edit:

> EDIT: Is it eligible to say that we are returning a pointer to x? If so, can you explain how is this done exactly? I mean, how are we returning a pointer?

Yes, it is certainly eligible. Try and think of and treat pointers as any other data type. Under the hood, they are just memory addresses. A pointer can be returned the same way any other data type can be returned.

Take this code for example:

```
int* giveMeAPointer() {
  return y;
}
int* x = giveMeAPointer();
```

Say that "y" is declared globally as: "int* y = ...". Now the memory address being pointed to by "x" is the same as the memory address being pointed to by "y".

Now let's say that "y" was -not- declared as a pointer, but instead as a normal int (e.g. "int y = 5"). The function could do this and still be valid:

```
int* giveMeAPointer() {
  int* result = &y;
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`*x` is points to int typed variable in memory. So function `func` should return address to int.

```
int *x;
x = new int;          // create your own int 
*x = 5;               // access - set it's value
delete x;             // delete int - free memory
x = getGlobalCounter();
(*x)++;               // increment global pointer
```

For example the getGlobalCounter function:

```
static int counter;
int *getGlobalCounter() {
   return &counter;   // return address of counter
}
```

But isn't always good idea to delete objects returned from functions. In that case it should result in runtime error, because of counter isn't dynamically allocated `int` as in top example.

Answer (score 2):

If you are assigning a variable's value to the return-type of a function, then that return-type must match the variable's type. This goes the same for pointers.

So, if you have:

```
int* myPointer;
```

And...

```
int* func();
```

Then setting myPointer equal to func() will change the memory address which "myPointer" points to, to the memory address returned by func().

Answer (score 1):

The statement just reads that x is assigned the value returned by function `func`. For the code to compile without errors , the func should return an address though . And for the code to execute as expected as `AlexFZ` pointed out , you should take care that `func` does not return the address of a variable local to the function.

Answer (score 0):

It means that func() returns a variable of type int*.

> Is it eligible to say that we are returning a pointer to x?

No, we are returning a pointer to an integer and assigning it to x since it is a pointer.

This is an example code which returns an int pointer
    `int* func(int a)

    {

        int *y = &a;

        return y;

    }`